# What is the story behind the celebration of the Magha Navaratri?

Tags: goddess, dasha-mahavidya, navrathri

I read somewhere that tomorrow is the beginning of the Magha Navaratri in which the Mahavidyas are worshipped. What is the story behind this celebration can anyone share something from the Puranas or other scriptures?